characterizing orientability of connected manifold with the number of conneted components on determinant bundle without zero
i want to build a characterization of orientability of a connected manifold $M^n$ with the number of connected components on the determinant bundle without zero $\tilde{M} := \coprod_{p \in M} \Lambda^n T^*_pM\setminus\{0\}$ which uses the subspace topology of the determinant bundle.
More precisely, i want to show

$\tilde{M}$ has exactly 2 connected components iff $M$ is orientable
$\tilde{M}$ is connected iff $M$ is non-orientable.

the following is my attempt(plz point out gaps or falsehoods inside it, or give new ideas and intuitions or deliver a short and sweet pf)

Lemma projection $\tilde{M}\xrightarrow{p} M$ is an open map.
Since $\tilde{M}$ is a subspace of the determinant bundle with a countable base $\{B_{n,m}\times I_k\}$ where $n$ is the index of a countable atlas, $B_{n,m}$ is the $m-th$ base of the $n-th$ chart, $I_k$ is the $k-th$ interval of the base of $\mathbb{R} \simeq \Lambda^n T^*_pM$, $\tilde{M}$ also has a countable base $$\{B_{n,m}\times (I_k \setminus \{0\})\}, $$
since a mapping preserves union, and since $p(B_{n,m}\times (I_k \setminus \{0\})\})= B_{n,m}$ is a base element of $M$, for any $U:= \bigcup B_{n,m}\times (I_k \setminus \{0\}) $, the image $$p(U)= p(\bigcup B_{n,m}\times ( I_k \setminus \{0\})\})= \bigcup p(B_{n,m}\times (I_k \setminus \{0\})\}) = \bigcup B_{n,m}$$ hence $p$ is an open map.
Speculation if $A$ is a connected component in $\tilde{M}$, then $p(A)=M$
My intuition tell me that if $p(A)^c$ as a closed subset is nonempty, then could attach some pts of $p^{-1}\partial p(A)^c$ to $A$ to make it a larger connected subset. Another idea is to prove $p(A)$ is closed, but open surjective continuous map might fail to be closed, and although $p(A)^c \subset p(A^c)$(since $p$ is surjective) the converse might not be true, hence i still could not conclude $p(A)$ closed easily.
Assuming the speculation is true, then
Step 1 $\tilde{M}$ has at most 2 components
Suppose $\tilde{M}$ has 3(other cases are likewise) connected components $A,B,C$, then pick a $p \in M$, the inclusion map is continuous:
$$\mathbb{R}_{<0}\coprod\mathbb{R}_{>0}\simeq\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \simeq \Lambda^n T^*_pM\setminus\{0\}\xrightarrow{i} \tilde{M}=: A \coprod B \coprod C$$
since continous injection preimage preserves boolean operations openness/closeness, $$\Lambda^n T^*_pM\setminus\{0\} = i^{-1}A \coprod i^{-1}B \coprod i^{-1}C$$, however by the above speculation, all components meet $p^{-1}(\{p\})$ somewhere, hence all of the 3 preimages of components are non-empty. However $\Lambda^n T^*_pM\setminus\{0\}$ has only 2 connected components, arriving at the contradiction.
Step 2 if $\tilde{M}$ has exactly 2 components $A,B$, then $M$ is orientable
Lemma On each fiber, the addition of 2 vectors in $A$ is still in $A$; the positive multiple of a vector in $A$ is also in $A$
since for a point $p\in M$ using the above inclusion, $i^{-1}A$ and $i^{-1}B$ must both be nonempty clopen in $\Lambda^n T^*_p M$, hence via a suitable trivialization, corresponds to $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$.
now choose a trivialization cover of determinant bundle $\{\tilde{U}_\alpha\xrightarrow{\Phi_\alpha} x_\alpha(U_\alpha) \times \mathbb{R}\}$ together with partition of unity $\{\rho_\alpha\}$, then for each patch $\tilde{U}_\alpha \cap A$, fix a point $a_\alpha$, write $\Phi(a_\alpha)=: (m_\alpha,v_\alpha)$, define $$s_\alpha: m \mapsto (m,v_\alpha)$$ for $m \in U$, then $\Phi^{-1}_\alpha\circ s_\alpha$ is a local section over $U$ with values in $A$, hence $$\sum_\alpha \rho_\alpha \Phi_\alpha^{-1} \circ s_\alpha $$ is a global section with values in $A$, hence we have construct a nowhere zero volume form over $M$.
Step3 If $M$ orientable, then $\tilde{M}$ has 2 components.
since the determinant bundle has a global frame, it is bundle isomorphic to $M \times \mathbb{R}$, hence $\tilde{M}$ is homeomorphic to $M \times \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$, which has exactly 2 components.

Also i couldn't find more references about the topology on determinant bundle, or more generally, line bundles that are not too involved(i.e., readable for a novice with only background of differentiable manifold and general topology), any that kind of references would be appreciated :)

Lemma 1 is correct, but I think working with bases is a bit cumbersome. If $U\subseteq\tilde{M}$ is open, to show that $p(U)$ is open in $M$, it suffices to find an open cover $(V_i)_{i\in I}$ of $M$ such that each $p(U)\cap V_i$ is open in $V_i$ respectively. If we take an atlas as this cover, $p(U)\cap V_i=p(U\cap p^{-1}(V_i))$ is open because the projection $p^{-1}(V_i)\cong V_i\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow V_i$ is an open map. The role of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ here is irrelevant; the proof holds for any fiber bundle. However, I also propose we don't need this Lemma.
The Speculation is true by some basic algebraic topology. Indeed, any fiber bundle is a Serre fibration and, in particular, satisfies the path-lifting property. That is, if you have a path in $\gamma\colon[0,1]\rightarrow M$ and a point $x\in\tilde{M}$ such that $p(x)=\gamma(0)$, there is a path $\tilde{\gamma}\colon[0,1]\rightarrow\tilde{M}$ such that $p\circ\tilde{\gamma}=\gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(0)=x$. If $x\in A$, then $\tilde{\gamma}$ takes values in $A$ by path-connectedness and $M$ is path-connected, so $p(A)=M$ follows. This, again, is true for arbitrary fiber bundles. The proof works by chopping $[0,1]$ into small pieces, each of which maps via $\gamma$ into a chart of the bundle and then lifting the path via a trivialization. This sort of argument is standard in any algebraic topology textbook, see e.g. Proposition 4.48 in Hatcher's book (which proves something more general).
The proofs of Step 1, 2 and 3 are correct.
I think everything here can also be recast nicely in the language of algebraic topology. In general, if $p\colon E\rightarrow B$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $F$ over a basepoint $b\in B$ and $B$ is path-connected, there is an "action up to homotopy" of the fundamental group $\pi_1(B,b)$ on $F$, which induces a bona fide action of $\pi_1(B,b)$ on the set of path-components $\pi_0(F)$, called the monodromy action (you may have encountered this in the context of covering spaces). The map $\pi_0(F)\rightarrow\pi_0(E)$ induced by the inclusion $F\subseteq E$ identifies the orbit space of this action with $\pi_0(E)$. In particular, the surjectivity implies that $E$ cannot have more components than $F$ (this gives an algebraic alternative to the geometric argument in your Step 1). In our case, $F=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ has only $2$ components, so we deduce that $E$ has $2$ components if and only if the monodromy action is trivial. If the $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$-bundle $E$ is obtained by deleting the zero section of a line bundle $L$, the argument of your Step $2$ shows that $L$ is trivial iff it admits a global section iff $E$ has $2$ components iff the monodromy action is trivial.
